# Why cannot be pointer free() after pointing to string literal

Tags: c

There are some related discussions about my problem but there are no clearly explanations about my problem.

I thought that I must `free()` whatever I `malloc()`, no matter when or where but I have to do it, to prevent a memory leak.
So i have the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(256);

    if (ptr == NULL)    {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    *ptr = 10;

    printf("The value of PTR is:\t%d\n",*ptr);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a pointer and I dynamically allocated  some memory (256), then I checked for `NULL` letter I `free()` it.

Until here everything is OK: to the pointer was dynamically allocated some memory and then I `free()` it.

Now i will use a char pointer this time and after i will dynamically allocated  some memory (256), i will point that pointer to a string literal, lets say MICHI:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(256);

    if (ptr == NULL)    {
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    ptr = "michi";
    printf("%s",ptr);

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here I am doing something wrong because if i try to `free()` it, well it will not work because it happens that i'm going to free a non-heap object.

So i'm lost in here, because i thought that everything you `malloc()` you have to `free()` it.
What exactly make that pointer, after points to a string literal, to not need to be `free()`ed

Comment: You allocated one chunk of memory, and pointed `ptr` to it. Then you pointed `ptr` to a *different* chunk of memory (the string literal). You've now lost track of the memory allocated via `malloc()`. You wanted to free *that*, but you tried to free the string literal instead. You don't free the pointer - you free the memory it points *to*.

Comment: So if i use malloc() on that pointer and latter i point that pointer to that string literal i do not have to think about free it, because it is now pointing somewhere else. Did i understand clearly ?

Comment: Don't free string literals. Free the memory returned by malloc. You need to use `strcpy` instead of `=` in the second program.

Comment: @Cool guy, i never free string literals but i found myself confused at that point, i was just thinking of that malloc only.

Comment: Passing a pointer value to `free` deallocates the chunk of memory that pointer points to. That chunk of memory *must* be one allocated by `malloc` or equivalent. This is valid: `char *ptr0 = malloc(256); char *ptr1 = ptr0; ptr0 = "foo"; free(ptr1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first program you allocated memory

```
ptr = malloc(256);
```

and initialized its first `sizeof( int )` bytes with integer value 10.

```
*ptr = 10;
```

The pointer itself was not changed. So in this statement

```
free(ptr);
```

pointer `ptr` points to the memory that was allocated using malloc.

In the second program you allocated memory the same way as in the first program

```
ptr = malloc(256);
```

But then you reassigned the pointer itself with the address of the first character of string literal "michi"

```
ptr = "michi";
```

Compare the left sides of this assignment

```
*ptr = 10;
```

and of this assignment

```
ptr = "michi";
```

As you see they are different. In the first case you are changing the allocated memory while in the second case you are changing the pointer itself.

Thus in this statement

```
free(ptr);
```

pointer `ptr` does not point to the memory that was previously allocated. It points to the memory occupied by the string literal that was not allocated using malloc.

Thus this statement is wrong and the program has a memory leak because the previous memory that was allocated using malloc was not freed,

Comment: How do I exactly free() the previous memory, or I have to avoid this kind of coding? Strcpy ?

Comment: @Michi To avoid memory leaks you should not write such code. You could copy the string literal in the allocated memory. For example strcpy( ptr, "michi" ); In this case you changed the allocated memory not the pointer itself and you can free the memory using the pointer. If you want that a pointer would point to a string literal then do not allocate memory. Just assign the pointer.

Answer (score 5):

```
ptr = malloc(256);
...
ptr = "michi";
printf("%s",ptr);
free(ptr);
```

As you allocate memory to `ptr` and then you make it point to `string literal`. Thus pointer `ptr` no longer points to memory allocated by `malloc`.

And to `free` memory not allocated by `malloc` or similar functions cause error in program.

Do this instead:

```
strcpy(ptr,"michi");
```

Answer (score 3):

Because constant literals are stored in a way for the lifetime of the program, in a read-only region of memory in most of the platforms.

When you use free you are trying to free the memory allocated, not the pointer itself, that's why it's not gonna work if you try to do that in a read-only region of memory

When you reassign your pointer you're losing track of the allocated memory and therefore creating a memory leak.
The memory leak is created because you first allocated the memory and assign it to your pointer, when you've a pointer pointing to it you can easily free that memory, but when you don't have any more reference to that memory you can't.
That's what's happening, when assign the literal to the pointer there's no more reference to that address, it was allocated but it's not reachable anymore, in this way you can't free the memory.

Comment: i know what a cosntant literal is, please read again my question.
@ Paul roub gave me the answer.

Comment: I added more information, anyway the problem was that, there was a misunderstanding of what exactly you were freeing. Hope it's clear now :)

Comment: You create a memory leak because the memory you allocated is not reachable by any mean anymore, that means you can't claim it anymore. I'll try to explain better in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have lost the pointer the second you assigned another value to it:

```
ptr = malloc(256);

if (ptr == NULL)    {
    printf("Out of memory\n");
    return 1;
}

// here you should free your memory
ptr = "michi";
printf("%s",ptr);

// this fails, because ptr now points to the const static string "michi" you have coded yourself. The assignment didn't copy it, just changed what ptr points to.
free(ptr);
```

Comment: This means that at this point the pointer, points to a different memory location ? This is the reason why i do not need to free() it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     char   *str:

     str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(str) * 4);
     printf("Addr of str before: %p\n", str);
     str = "Joe";
     printf("Addr of str after: %p\n",str);
     return(0);
}
```

/* you will get the following addresses:

Addr of str before: 0x51fc040
Addr of str after: 0x4006f0

this is becuase you changed where str points to. 0x51fc040 is memory allocated using malloc and 0x4006f0 is the memory Adress of the string literal "Joe".

I would advice the following...*/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     char    *str;

     str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(str) * 4);
     printf("Addr of str before: %p\n", str); 
     str =strncpy(str, "Joe", 4);
     printf("Addr of str after: %p\n",str);
     free(str);
     return (0);
}
```

/* you will get the following addresses:

Addr of str before: 0x51fc040
Addr of str after: 0x51fc040

This is because strncpy copies the string literal to the memory dynamically allocated. and it is safer than stcpy, since it prevents buffer overflow